# Saving multiple contenteditable id´s info to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, contenteditable

Here is the deal:

I have 100 html5 contenteditable fields each of them with an id.

What I am willing to accomplish is to save the data enetered by the user into localsotarge, so when he comes back to visit the site, doesn't have to re-enter info again.

The event for this to happen must be onkeyup.

The sample markup would be as follows:

```
<a href="#"  contenteditable="true" id="uniquevalue" onkeyup="myFunction();"><span class="item_price">$35.99</span></a><br>

 <a href="#"  contenteditable="true" id="anotheruniquevalue" onkeyup="myFunction();"><span class="item_price">$35.99</span></a><br>
```

I have seen samples on the internet, but as I am not a javascript expert, I would need to create 100 functions to actually do what I want.

I have loaded jquery for this project

I can thank you enough for taking the time to help me with this project.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be work:

```
$('a[contenteditable="true"]').on('keyup', function(event){
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).html());
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TV6Es/)

Comment: Just to be clear all I have to do is paste this script, and no other action or trigger will be needed inside my contenteditable items right ?

Comment: When I reload the page the new entered values are replaced by their defaults. Am I missign something ? Thank you for your support

Comment: Well you need to actually reload the data from localStorage when the page loads.

Comment: Please can you explain me the last step ?